# why MySQL store backslash with double quotation marks in the data table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

why MySQL store backslash with double quotation marks in the data table.
any way to restrict that?

for example
I have stored some HTML in the database but I want to show in the front side but it's show backslash with double quotation

i have stored 
`<div class=\"droppable\" ondrop=\"drop(event)\" ondragover=\"allowDrop(event)\">`

but i want to display `<div class="droppable" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">`

here is my PHP code

```
function bookmypte_question()
{
    $question;
    ?>
<html>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
    Question: <textarea name="question" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit"></form>
</body>
</html>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    global $wpdb;
    $question=$_POST['question'];

    $table_name2 = $wpdb->prefix . 'pte_question'; 
    $wpdb->insert(
        $table_name2,
            array(
    'question' => $question)
); echo "inserted";}}
```

Comment: How are you inserting it? That's more likely to be the problem. Use prepared statements. Show the insertion code.

Comment: I have inserted in textarea with the insert query.

Comment: Show the code (edited and formatted in the question), not a description of the code.

Comment: function bookmypte_question()
{
    $question;
    ?>
<html>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
    Question: <textarea name="question" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit"></form>
</body>
</html>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    global $wpdb;
    $question=$_POST['question'];
    
    $table_name2 = $wpdb->prefix . 'pte_question'; 
    $wpdb->insert(
        $table_name2,
            array(
    'question' => $question)
); echo "inserted";}}

Comment: @danblack here I inserted code in question.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired Data from Database using wp_unslash() that ignores the forward slashes before and after (single and double quotes), so ignore how WordPress store Data in Database you simple ignore it.

```
output before using `wp_unslash()`
       \"https://www.googletagmanager.com\"
    
    <?PHP
     $content = wp_unslash(get_option('data-content'));
     echo $content;
    ?>
    
    output  after  using `wp_unslash()`
      "https://www.googletagmanager.com"
```